# How can I display response data from apex controller in dataTable?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, api, datatable, js

I want to display data that I'm getting from API response in a datatable.

The APEX method returns JSON in this format:

```json
{
    "data": [
        [
            "765919758146423601",
            "5ebd304a4cec1000",
            "2021-01-13T18:38:05",
            "1920x1080",
            [
                0,
                "Desktop"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "2402015774021312251",
            "48566e2f521a4000",
            "2021-01-12T21:19:48",
            "1920x1080",
            [
                0,
                "Desktop"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "3472999688268527503",
            "af3b292e27638000",
            "2021-01-12T22:45:36",
            "1920x1080",
            [
                0,
                "Desktop"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "7787867248858577125",
            "7ffb01dfb283d400",
            "2021-01-14T09:02:02",
            "1920x1080",
            [
                0,
                "Desktop"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "10928117865478904202",
            "84132d38a08b2000",
            "2021-01-14T11:05:20",
            "1920x1080",
            [
                0,
                "Desktop"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "14601725682851508262",
            "a3c3730b1fd0ab14",
            "2021-01-15T03:31:55",
            "1920x1080",
            [
                0,
                "Desktop"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "meta": {
        "columns": [
            "session_id",
            "visitor_id",
            "timestamp",
            "resolution",
            "device_type"
        ],
        "count": 6
    }
}
```

The columns of the datatable are set dynamically in this manner:

```js
for (var i in mustHaveSessionLabelColumns) {
   dataTableColumnList.push({
      label: mustHaveSessionLabelColumns[i],
      fieldName: responseList[i],
      type: 'text'
    }); 
}
component.set("v.columns",dataTableColumnList);
```

When I test the aura:app I get correct amount of columns with correct fieldName&type (Checked with console.log) but I have trouble mapping the responseData to datatable data="v.dataTableData"

```html
<lightning:datatable
    keyField="id"
    data="{!v.dataTableData}"
    columns="{! v.columns }"
    hideCheckboxColumn="true"
    resizeColumnDisabled="true"
    minColumnWidth="100"
    maxColumnWidth="1000" 
    showRowNumberColumn="true"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **parse** your **JSON** into JavaScript Object and then manipulate with that object.

If you always get **the same JSON format** the Code for you will look in next way :

**Apex** :

```java
public with sharing class ParseJsonIntoDatatableController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string getJSONData(){
        try {
            String jsonData;
            // somw your logic which gets JSON Data
            return jsonData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Aura JS : **

```js
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        // helper constant for column Labels
        const columnLabelMap = {
            session_id : 'Session Id',
            visitor_id : 'Visitor Id',
            timestamp : 'Time',
            resolution : 'Resolution',
            device_type : 'Device Type',
        }
        var action = component.get("c.getJSONData");
        // the callback for parsing data from JSON
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let responseData = JSON.parse( response.getReturnValue() );
                let dataTableColumns = []
                responseData.meta.columns.forEach( column => {
                    dataTableColumns.push( 
                        {
                            label : columnLabelMap[column] ? columnLabelMap[column] : column,
                            fieldName : column,
                            type: 'text'
                        }
                    )
                });
                component.set( "v.columns" , dataTableColumns );
                let dataForDatatable = []
                responseData.data.forEach( element => {
                    dataForDatatable.push( 
                        {
                            session_id : element[0],
                            visitor_id : element[1],
                            timestamp : element[2],
                            resolution : element[3],
                            device_type : element[4][1],
                        }
                    )
                });
                component.set( "v.dataTableData" , dataForDatatable );
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Aura HTML : **

```html
<aura:component controller="ParseJsonIntoDatatableController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="dataTableData" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <!-- handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>


    <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable
            keyField="session_id"
            data="{! v.dataTableData }"
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true"
            resizeColumnDisabled="true"
            minColumnWidth="100"
            maxColumnWidth="1000" 
            showRowNumberColumn="true"
        ></lightning:datatable>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Note :**
*this code will only work for your **JSON** format,

you can modify the parser for your wishes,

it will be good to set the column types **dynamically** as well*

With that **code** you will get the next **datatable**
[image]

Comment: What if the number of columns are dynamic based on multiselect picklist and the data should be mapped appropriately?

Comment: @Stojcheski I mentioned that this solution for particular JSON. In your case you need to get this picklist at first and then based on the picklist length and order create the data for the data-table.

Comment: So I would need another forEach loop for all columns  before responseData.data.forEach and then .push column[0] : element[0], column[1] : element[1] or? I have posted the question for exact this problem that's why I'm bothering you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @Maria You are welcome, Please accept this answer as the one which resolved your issue. Thanks